# Overriding listeners and threads

Tags: java, coding-style, overriding

Is it a good idea to override(implement) listener or thread behavior in the current code or make a new class that implements or extends it?

e.g.

```
public doSomething() {
    Thread thr = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            //thread business
        }
    };
    thr.start();
}
```

versus

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        //thread business
    }
}
......
public doSomething() {
    MyThread thr = new MyThread();
    thr.start();
}
```

Please point on all pros and cons ot these two practices.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The 1st way of doing is never a good idea. When we do it this way, you actually create an inner class. And since inner classes have a implicit property of holding the object of the parent class, it may lead to memory leaks.

The 2nd option creating a new class in its own file is always better, for the above reason.

Edit 2:

The 1st way of doing is never a good idea. When we do it this way, you actually create an inner class. And since inner classes have a implicit property of holding the object of the parent class, it may lead to memory leaks.

The 2nd option creating a new class in its own file is always better, for the above reason.

Edit 2:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    private WeakReference<Button> mButton;

    public MyThread(Button button) {
        mButton = new WeakReference(button);
        // Use this button where-ever you want
    }

    public void run() {
        //thread business
    }
}
......
Button btn = ...;
public doSomething() {
    MyThread thr = new MyThread(btn);
    thr.start();
}
```

Comment: If the anonymous inner class makes use of the implicit reference to the surrounding class the 2nd option is not necessarily better. Besides, it isn't necessary to subclass Thread, in nearly all cases it is sufficient to implement the Runnable interface.

Comment: Sagar, how do you deal with accesibility from the Runnable object to the object that uses it? For example, if I want to create new thread for some on-page animation purposes (e.g. button slowly changing it's color) do you implement runnable in such way that it takes button as a parameter?

Comment: Thanks, I share this point of view. It is better to limit thread access to main class and stuff it with objects it really needs. What about listeners? Is it too hard to implement listener for every element in it's own class?